# how to pass todays date in the url/session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms-1.6

So in the view if the user is currently logged in 'Book Now' appears, which navigates them to 'Availability' controller / 'Index' function. I want to pass todays date as a session?

any ideas? thanks
Note: using orchard 1.6

```
@if(WorkContext.CurrentUser != null) 
    {
    @Html.ActionLink(T("Book Now").Text, "Index", new { Controller = "Availability", Area = "Project0120" })
    }
```

**EDIT**
I am trying ti display a list of bookings for a month. Originally I set the loop to 30, for a default. Now that I have the code inside the loop working. i only want to run through the loop how many days are in this month...so i was trying

var dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
to get todays date, then I wanted to use the days as the maximum in the loop

for (int i = 1; i <= dateAsString.?getdays?; i ++)

Comment: Whats does "pass todays date as a session" mean?

Comment: well i meant put todays date as a session and pass it in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to consider server date, in your case when user clicks on Action Link Controller-Action will be called and in side same action just take the Server Date with DateTime.Now. Try to avoid client side date generation as much as you can.

Comment: thanks for reply Hi10....so im using var dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); now instead of having for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i ++) what can i change the 30 to? dateAsString.getDay???

Comment: You get directly get the Day from DateTime.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it on first :) 
example: int day = DateTime.Now.Day;

Comment: thanks for reply, yeah that gives todays number...so it is returning '3' i want to return the total number of days for this month

Comment: int numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month);